# return of arrow function on the same line, typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have the following code:

```
computed: {
  todos(): Todo[] {
    return this.$store.getters['todos/list']
  }
}
```

but I would like something like this::

```
computed: {
  todos: (): Todo[] => this.$store.getters['todos/list']
}
```

nas I get the following error

[image]

on terminal
[image]

how to make it work so that the computed property returns on the same line?

thanks for everything

Comment: Where is $store declared? it is complaining because it can't find $store within the current `this` context. Fat arrow functions change the `this` context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you shouldnt do it like that. Its described in the docs

[image]

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Comment: do you understand vue + typescript?

Comment: I mean, do you have experience?

Comment: @YungSilva just vue, i have never done something with typescript, maybe i learn it in the future

Comment: oh it's ok :) i also use vue for some time, but it's been painful to use vue with typescript, i have a little problem, but as you don't have experience with typescript + vue, it's ok hehe